# Monitor to restart application whenever it freezes or exits

Tags: applications

I want to have a certain GUI-based application always running.  It goes spinning-beachball a lot.  How do I make sure it is always running, restarting it whenever it freezes or exits?

Comment: Perhaps figuring out why the app beachballs so frequently would be a first step.

Comment: it's just an old crappy application I have to run for work.  killing and restarting it would be just fine.